# XML to retrieve TxnID

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

Unable to query TxnID from an invoice

Can't find the exact tag to return the requested element.
For example, lets assume the following;

Customer:  Main Corp
Invoice:  500001
Amt:  50,000.00

what xml script would I use to retrieve this specific invoice TxnID

Thank you

Comment: Hi Mike, can you add what you have already tried to your question? Maybe tell people what does not work?

Comment: I am all new to this.  I have some experience with this xml programing, but this specific function I have no clue where to begin and where to start

Comment: Alright, so, I also don't have any knowledge in this area but I would like to help you formulate your question so that people that do have it, can help you. You say "Unable to query", but you haven't tried anything yet? Also, what do you mean with "find the exact tag"? and the "requested element"? You should really try to extend your answer. SO is not a place where people are going to do the work for you, but are willing to help you find a proper solution to your problem.

Comment: You haven't told us what programming language you're using, or what you've tried so far, or if even what you want to query by (is it the invoice # that you have?). You'll need to give us some additional context here.